# 0 Active Connections after Connection reset in Hikari CP

Tags: java, spring-boot, database-connection, connection-pooling, hikaricp

Running a cron job via springboot app which has DB intensive I/O calls that can go on and on till 5-6 hours. Since hikari cp is connection pool that comes by default, The connection is getting reset due to some reason and when that single connection goes down, my pool has 0 active connections making the application not perform any further business logic since connection is not available.

Would really appreciate any help on this. Getting the below exception...

```
2020-09-23 23:40:33.890 || [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-57] WARN  c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - HikariPool-1 - Connection ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: faea82a1-e6b0-439f-a0b6-5f04d59988bd marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2670)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1993)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6494)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:7738)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:546)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:479)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7344)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2713)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:224)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:204)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:401)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2815)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2797)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2629)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2624)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1396)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1009)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:997)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:990)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:948)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1983)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

---

```
2020-09-23 23:40:37.454 || [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection ConnectionID:47 ClientConnectionId: 83a7b7f7-fdac-4d6e-a20d-7a6d6726e7e8
2020-09-23 23:40:37.454 || [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection ConnectionID:47 ClientConnectionId: 83a7b7f7-fdac-4d6e-a20d-7a6d6726e7e8
2020-09-23 23:40:37.454 || [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After adding stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2020-09-24 00:00:08.509 || [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2020-09-24 00:00:08.509 || [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2020-09-24 00:00:38.536 || [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2020-09-24 00:00:38.536 || [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2020-09-24 00:01:08.540 || [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2020-09-24 00:01:08.540 || [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2020-09-24 00:01:38.544 || [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2020-09-24 00:01:38.544 || [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
```

And application is not recovering after this and all threads are getting parked.

```
Environment
SpringBoot:2.2.2 RELEASE
```

Comment: Did you eventually solve this issue ? If so how did you do it ?